# Javascript FormData() File Upload to S3 works in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: javascript, file-upload, amazon-s3, safari

Working on a web app, I have image files going directly to the S3 bucket from the browser.  This works well in Chrome, but in Safari there are no errors, but the code ends up uploading an empty file to the S3 bucket.  Everything basically looks like it works in Safari, the S3 server even returns a `204` successful http response, and the file looks like it is in the bucket (but has a size of 0 bytes).

I debugging, and the `blobData` has size 55747 in Chrome but only size 47560 in Safari for the same image.  Also, I have found what looks slightly different is in the networking section dev tools:

Chrome - working (204 response has positive size ~ 534B):

[image]

Safari - not working with empty file ( size column shows just a dash line )

[image]

Here is the JS upload code:

```
    function uploadFile(data_url, s3Data, url, filename, id, thumbnail_url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", s3Data.url);

        var postData = new FormData();
        for(key in s3Data.fields){
            postData.append(key, s3Data.fields[key]);
        }

        var blobData = dataURItoBlob(data_url);

        postData.append('file', new File([blobData], filename));

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState === 4){
                if(xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 204){
                    setTimeout(function(){

                        $('#photo_container').append('<div id="image_container_'+id+'" class="hover-card mdl-cell--3-col-desktop mdl-cell--2-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone mdl-shadow--2dp"></div>');

                        $('.star-image').unbind('click').click( star_image_click );
                        $('.close-image').unbind('click').click(remove_image_click);
                        loading_files -= 1;
                        if ( loading_files == 0 ) {
                            $('#photo_load_spinner').removeClass('is-active');
                            $('#photo_load_text').text("");
                        }else{
                            $('#photo_load_text').text(loading_files+" files loading.  Please wait.");
                        }

                    }, 1000);


                }else{
                    alert("Could not upload file. "+xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(postData);
    }

    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
    }
```

I am kind of at a loss as to what to look for next.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just figure I should give a little more information.  The `data_url` is generated from a canvas element which I use to resize the image in the browser, although I have confirmed that the canvas shows the image correctly in safari before upload.  Here is that code:

```
    function ResizeFile(raw_file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");

            img.onload = function() {

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                //ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                var MAX = 1200;
                var width = img.width;
                var height = img.height;

                if (width > height) {
                  if (width > MAX) {
                    height *= MAX / width;
                    width = MAX;
                  }
                } else {
                  if (height > MAX) {
                    width *= MAX / height;
                    height = MAX;
                  }
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, width, height);

                var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                getSignedRequest(dataurl);

            }

            img.src = e.target.result;

        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(raw_file);
    }
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm having the same issue at the moment, I've been stuck on it for days now

Comment: @user2634633 well... kinda solved it.  So it terms out it is an important security feature of Safari navigator.  It doesn't not allow programs to alter the content of file inputs.  The idea behind the security is that it will only allow uploads of files that the user actually picks himself.  So the way I worked around was to use a normal file input element in the form, and upload from that.  I decided to not do the image resize before upload, but did that processing on the S3 server after uploading the entire file.

Comment: thanks for the info. I ended up cropping and resizing on the client and sending the data URI to a server, which converts it to a file and does S3 upload. It's a bit circuitous but can't think of anything better.

Comment: @user2634633 this way you still have to upload the file back to your server first, right?  But i guess if you resize it on the client you save a little on the upload back to your server, but you lose the resource savings of direct upload from client to s3.

Comment: I take that back - I've just managed to make it work with client upload from Safari. The problem was in my scaling code, not the upload code. I set `image.src` synchronously, while it's an asynchronous action, even when used with a specific data URI. On Chrome, that was not a problem, but on Safari, image height and width got set to 0, because I didn't wait for the image to load - hence, 0b file size. Check if your `data_url` is the same on Safari and Chrome. After making my scaling function asynchronous by using `image.onload` callback everything is working fine!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind stuck with the same problem. I am uploading screenshot taken from safari extension. How do I upload thar to s3, when the screenshot file is stored in a variable (and not an input)

Answer (score 3):

We could resize image file and upload to server. Tested on Chrome and Safari, both works fine.

```
fileChange() {

    var fileInputTag = document.getElementById("myFile");

    if ('files' in fileInputTag) {
        if (fileInputTag.files.length > 0) {

            var file = fileInputTag.files[0];

            var type = 'image/jpeg',
            maxWidth = 800,
            maxHeight = 600,
            quality = 0.5,
            ratio = 1,

            canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            context = canvas['getContext']('2d'),
            canvasCopy = document.createElement('canvas'),
            copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext('2d'),

            img = new Image();

            img.onload = function () {
              if (img.width > maxWidth) {
                ratio = maxWidth / img.width;
              } else if (img.height > maxHeight) {
                ratio = maxHeight / img.height;
              }

              canvasCopy.width = img.width;
              canvasCopy.height = img.height;
              copyContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
              canvas.width = img.width * ratio;
              canvas.height = img.height * ratio;
              context.drawImage(canvasCopy, 0, 0, canvasCopy.width, canvasCopy.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

              canvas.toBlob((blob) =>  {
                blob['name'] = file.name.split('.')[0] + '.jpeg';

                var formData:FormData = new FormData();
                formData.append('uploadFile', blob, blob.name);

                // do upload here

              }, type, quality);

            };

            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        }
    }
}
```

Add this to index.html or execute it before above script execution

```
if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', {
    value: function (callback, type, quality) {

        var binStr = atob( this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1] ),
            len = binStr.length,
            arr = new Uint8Array(len);

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember Safari having limited support for FormData objects, for example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get

Comment: the big read "No Support" for the `set` function doesn't look good.  Thanks, although there is a red `?` for the `append` method which I am using.

Comment: Not sure but they have those 2 footnotes there:

[1] Prior to Gecko 7.0 (Firefox 7.0 / Thunderbird 7.0 / SeaMonkey 2.4), if you specified a Blob as the data to append to the object, the filename reported in the "Content-Disposition" HTTP header was an empty string; this resulted in errors being reported by some servers. Starting in Gecko 7.0 the filename "blob" is sent.



[2] XHR in Android 4.0 sends empty content for FormData with blob.

I am assuming something like partially compliant?

Comment: Yeah I am looking at workarounds and it seems it isn't complete secure to allow the developer to set the value of a file input.  The broswer is only supposed to let the user select the file...